# C++ map comparsion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stdmap

Good morning, I'm stuck using a map in the correct way.

**Situation**

A database table with unique ID and two other codes

```
ID (long) | Type (long) | Name (string)
```

to fill the map correctly I've defined it in this way:

```
map<long, MyObject>
```

where key is my ID and the object holds all the stuff. The map works correctly, I load all rows and I navigate easily inside of it.

**Troubles**

Troubles come when I need to sort the rows using a criteria which is not the key but:

1. Type
2. Name

Looking around the Internet I found that I should:

1. Define the operator< for MyObject or...
2. Define another type of comparator for my map.

I did the step 1., but with no success (it is never called). I'm trying to do the point 2. but with even less success.
I'll paste some code to help:

```
class CSitoWebRigaVariante
{
public:
    bool    m_bSriDelete;
    bool    m_bSriVisibile;
    long    m_lSriId;
    long    m_lSriIdTipol;
    long    m_lSriCodGes;
    CString m_strSriCodMat;
public:
    CSitoWebRigaVariante(void);
    CSitoWebRigaVariante(const CSitoWebRigaVariante& cRiga);
    ~CSitoWebRigaVariante(void);
    bool operator<(const CSitoWebRigaVariante& cRiga);
    void operator=(const CSitoWebRigaVariante& cRiga);
    void Azzera(void);
    static void CaricaDaMDB(CDB* pDB, long lIdVM, map<long, CSitoWebRigaVariante>& cRighe);
};
typedef map<long, CSitoWebRigaVariante> CSWRighe;

///> Static method to fill a map.
void CSitoWebRigaVariante::CaricaDaMDB(CADODatabase* pDB, long lIdVM, map<long, CSitoWebRigaVariante>& cRighe)
{
    BOOL                    bValRit;
    CRecordset*         pRS;
    CSitoWebRigaVariante    riga;
    CString                 strInt;

    pRS = new CADORecordset(pDB);
    strInt.Format(_T("SELECT * FROM SITOWEB_RIVARMAT WHERE sri_idvarmat = %ld;"), lIdVM);
    cRighe.clear();
    if (pRS->Open(strInt, CADORecordset::openQuery) == TRUE && pRS->GetRecordCount() > 0)
    {
        while (pRS->IsEOF() == FALSE)
        {
            bValRit = pRS->GetFieldValue(_T("sri_id"), riga.m_lSriId);
            bValRit &= pRS->GetFieldValue(_T("sri_idtipol"), riga.m_lSriIdTipol);
            bValRit &= pRS->GetFieldValue(_T("sri_codges"), riga.m_lSriCodGes);
            bValRit &= pRS->GetFieldValue(_T("sri_codmat"), riga.m_strSriCodMat);
            bValRit &= pRS->GetFieldValue(_T("sri_delete"), riga.m_bSriDelete);
            bValRit &= pRS->GetFieldValue(_T("sri_visibile"), riga.m_bSriVisibile);
            cRighe.insert(pair<long, CSitoWebRigaVariante>(riga.m_lSriCodGes, riga));
            pRS->MoveNext();
        }
    }
    pRS->Close();
    delete pRS;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, MFC.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` is not a multi-index associative container. Its `find` method (and other things) uses the key as a search criteria. There's no possibility to specify another search criteria. It's why it's a "single-index lookup table".

You can use [**Boost.MultiIndex**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). It was designed for your case and supports multiple indexes (as the name suggests), both unique and not-unique.

Or you can use multiple map instances with different keys. If keys are not unique you need `std::multimap`.

Comment: I still don't get the point: ID is unique, Type and Name not, why using multiple index? Shouldn't I redefine sort criteria, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @IssamTP: elaborated the answer

Comment: Basically I should define something like: class CKey { long id; long type; string name; operator<( CKey one, CKey two ) {/*mysort criteria*/}} even if I would have problem in accessing the members. Well, thanks.

Comment: I used a multimap instead of map and I got the results I was looking for. Despite this, I lost some fast "indicization" and had to rewrite some part of code. Probably I should have follow the hint of @v-kravchenko and use a separate load-sort.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use map for model (for storing data). When you need to display information, you can just output it in the order you need it to be shown. Sorting must be done not at level of storing items, but at level of displaying them. 
Although, in each situation you will need to do reordering only once.

Also, if any help is appreciated, I would strongly recommend you to do a

```
typedef long MyId;
```

and to use VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The `map` class provides a Compare parameter of the constructor. You could not complete your target by setting Compare as `map` has only support key compare function.

The first idea of mine is construct a class support your tables schema.

```
class Example
{
    public:
        <your code>
        void sortByID();
        void sortByType();
        void sortByName();

    private:
        long ID_;
        long Type_;
        string Name_;
};
```

But it sounds terrible. As once your table change, you should hard copy.So why you just get result using database `order by`?